# Cannot add wep.api controller in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: asp.net-web-api, controller, visual-studio-2019

I have a Web API project that I need to add a empty Wep API 2 controller to, when I try to that I get this error from Visual Studio:

> There was an error running the selected code generator:
>   'The value -1 is outside the acceptable range of [0,2147483647].
>   Parameter name value'

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved in Visual Studio 2019 version 16.2.4. The release notes are available here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes#16.2.4

Comment: I got this error verified as a bug in VS 2019. It will be fixed in VS 2019 version 16.2.4.

Comment: Visual Studio 2019 version 16.2.4 is now available. See more details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes#16.2.4

Comment: Yes, and here is info about the fix for this bugg. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/626755/error-running-the-selected-code-generator-value-1.html

Answer (score 0):

this issue only happens when the web.config file is open in the editor. Please close the web.config file & try the scaffolding scenario again. This worked for me.